# How to understand that a Core Data Entity key is sortable?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have created a generic function to check the validity of sort descriptors:

```
func _areValid(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor], of type: Object.Type) -> Bool {

    var inputKeys: Set<String> = []
    sortDescriptors.forEach { if let key = $0.key { inputKeys.insert(key) } }

    if inputKeys.isSubset(of: Set(type.entity().attributesByName.keys)) { return true }
    else { return false }
}
```

It allows verifying that keys in the NSSortDescriptor really are the Entity keys. The problem is that a key can exist, but can be unsortable. For example, UUID. How can I check it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to check the `attributeType` field on each attribute, and only allow specific types. There's no way that I know of to get from the attribute type to a sortability check without just listing the types that are permitted.

For a UUID attribute, the attribute type is `UUIDAttributeType`. This corresponds to a property of type `UUID`. But there's nothing about `UUIDAttributeType` or the `UUID` struct definition that makes this clear. It only comes up in documentation. You can look up attribute types but there's no built-in way to check whether some attribute type value corresponds to something you can use in a sort descriptor.

At some point when you look up the `attributesByName`, you'll need to look at each attribute and return `false` for `UUIAttributeType` and anything else you don't want to allow. It's not ideal but I think it's the only way.

As an aside I'd be extremely interested to know what you're doing that makes this check necessary.

Comment: Nothing special :-) Just a helper for my Core Data layer, that I can use in several projects.